# wpf user control blocking styles

Tags: wpf, styles

I am making a wpf class library with some user controls in it.  Some of my controls are not styled and so whatever style is defined in the app that hosts my control is applied to my controls.  This creates a bad mix of looks.

I need my user control to specify that all controls need to use just the default wpf look and feel regardless of what the parent form is doing.

Answer (score 0):

try style="{x:null}"